# Selection of jdbc driver for oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jakarta-ee

Which jdbc driver should be used for connecting with oracle 8i? I am using jdk 1.6 and tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choices would be (in the decreasing order of preference):

- The JDBC driver that is provided with the database itself. This is typically found in the `jdbc/lib` directory of your Oracle database home.
- The most recent driver for the 8i platform. You can get this from [Oracle Technology Network](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). Use this if are encountering any issues (that are typically not patched in the driver supplied by the database).
- The JDBC driver that ships with the application server. This is listed as the last preference, for the 8i platform is quite old, and the drivers supplied would have better characteristics for newer releases like the 10g and 11g platforms.

If you are on Java 1.4 or newer, i.e. Java 1.4/5/6, then use the driver within `ojdbc_14.jar` instead of `classes12.zip`. The driver within `classes12.zip` is meant to be used on versions of Java after 1.2 and before 1.4.

If you do have `ojdbc5.jar` or `ojdbc6.jar` (unlikely to be the case for the 8i drivers), then they'll need to used in preference over `ojdbc14.jar`, in the Java 5 and Java 6 platforms respectively. Use these drivers (meant for the Java 5 and Java 6 platforms) with caution though, as the some of these driver versions will simply not be supported when used against an 8i database. For example, the [Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference for 11g R1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1008205) states the following:

> **Backward Compatibility**
>
> The JDBC drivers are certified to work
>   with the currently supported versions
>   of Oracle Database. For example, the
>   JDBC Thin drivers in Oracle Database
>   11g Release 1 (11.1) are certified to
>   work with the 10.2.x, 10.1.x, 9.2.x,
>   and 9.0.1.x Oracle Database releases.
>   However, they are not certified to
>   work with older, unsupported database
>   releases, such as 8.0.x and 7.x.

The JDBC developer's guide for 10g R1/R2 might state the same, but you'll need to verify this if you intend to proceed with a driver version that works against a newer database release. In practice, ensure that you know the version of the driver in use, and that it is supported for use against 8i.

Comment: Thanks very much.Would you please tell me the meaning of the word "lieu" that you have used in your answer's second last line, due to this word i am unable to understand that important sentence.

Comment: There were no ojdbc5.jar or ojdbc6.jar files for Oracle 8i. The best one can do is to find an ojdbc_14.jar from older release of Oracle. JDBC drivers that are currently available for download from Oracle web site do not support Oracle 8i.

Comment: @Olaf, I was attempting to cover the scenario where newer drivers were used. I'll edit my answer. On the second topic, OTN does list the 8i drivers for download.

Comment: How are companies still using Oracle 8i? That was de-supported a decade ago!

Comment: @Adam, beats me. I didn't notice it until I started writing about the backward compatibility section.